# Aircon wall unit making noise like kettle when switched off

Tags: air-conditioning

We’ve had this Fujitsu 4kw unit for just under a year. I noticed even straight away when we got it after turning off it would make a sound like soft wind or a kettle (not screeching or whistling but like steam starting to softly come through the spout)

It now seems to do this for a long time after switching off, like half an hour or more

Is this a problem we should be concerned about?

Thanks

Comment: the compressed coolat is loosing pressure and returning to the tank.

Answer (score 2):

It's coolant boiling inside the unit.

It's absolutely normal.

Air conditioner use a liquid that that boils at a low pressure (like butane) and let it boil to make the cold, then they compress the vapour outdoors to make more liquid butane.

Comment: Being able to _hear_ it is, in any house I've been in the US, unusual. It may just be something to do with where the outdoor parts were installed.

Answer (score 0):

I would not be concerned.

Almost normal operation.

When you turn it on, the compressor compresses the coolant to very high pressure, that then circulates true the heat exchanger coil, and the fan blows air over it.

When you turn it off, the high pressure slowly reduces, and you hear that, because the Air conditioner is not longer running making all the noise.